# Extracting a value from dictionary in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to print just the 'Amount' value of 261795.588 from the following dictionary response in Python.

```
{'ResultsByTime': [{'TimePeriod': {'Start': '2018-09-01', 'End': '2018-10-01'}, 'Total': {'Cost': {'Amount': '261795.5886093237', 'Unit': 'USD'}}
```

I'm super noob with Python and could use a little guidance on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Access `dict` keys via syntax `D[key_name]`. Access `list` items by positions via `L[position]`.

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary you have is incorrectly formatted. Suppose your correct dictionary looks like this-

```
dict_ = {'ResultsByTime': [{'TimePeriod': {'Start': '2018-09-01', 'End': '2018-10-01'}, 'Total': {'Cost': {'Amount': '261795.5886093237', 'Unit': 'USD'}}]}
```

Then this should give you the value you need-

```
print(dict_['ResultsByTime'][0]['Total']['Cost']['Amount'])
```